# (Swift) How to parse JSON with struct?

Tags: json, swift

I want to parse JSON with struct and name it.

here is the JSON data:

```
{
"sgList": [
    {
        "ID": 11113,
        "Name": "soss",
        "Price": "10.0000",
        "BigImagesUrl": "http://192.165.1.19:886/img/1/2015/7/11/20157111429315728.png",
        "SmallImagesUrl": "http://192.165.1.19:886/img/1/2015/7/11/20157111429315728.png"
    },
    {
        "ID": 11958,
        "Name": "1017p-02",
        "Price": "0.0000",
        "BigImagesUrl": "http://192.165.1.13:886/img/rar-upload/f82f22ce-4a33-4ba2-a31d-4bae473f5d48/pics/797_1.jpg",
        "SmallImagesUrl": "http://192.165.1.13:886/img/rar-upload/f82f22ce-4a33-4ba2-a31d-4bae473f5d48/pics/797_1-[135-135].jpg"
    }
]
}
```

I spend hours on it and get nothing!
Please help me, Thank you very much!

Comment: Try to use this: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON It's very simple to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want an third party library and do it yourself, it's pretty easy.
Assuming that your JSON String is in a variable called `jsonString`

```
let data = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments)
```

Then you can access your data via subsript. For example if you want the *Name* of the second object in *sgList*

```
json["sgList"][1]["Name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using `SwiftyJSON`:

```
import SwiftyJSON

struct SqList {
    let sqList: Array<SqElement>

    init(json: JSON) {
       let sqArray = json["sqList"].arrayValue.flatMap { SqElement(json: $0) } 
       self.sqList = sqArray
    }
}

struct SqElement {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let price: String
    let bigImagesUrl: String
    let smallImagesUrl: String

    init?(json: JSON) {
        guard
            let id = json["ID"].string,
            let name = json["Name"].string,
            let price = json["Price"].string,
            let bigImagesUrl = json["BigImagesUrl"].string,
            let smallImagesUrl = json["SmallImagesUrl"].string
        else { return nil }

        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.bigImagesUrl = bigImagesUrl
        self.smallImagesUrl = smallImagesUrl
    }
}
```

In code you just call:

```
let sqList = SqList(json: JSON(data: dataWithJSON))
```